# Importar un XML con dos puntos (:) en el xpath

Tags: xml, google-hoja-de-cálculo, xpath

Estoy tratando de importar un *XML* en una hoja de cálculo de *Google* con [`importXML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=es).

Puedo extraer todos los campos como:

```
=importXML( URL, "//item/loquequiero")
```

Pero con los campos que empiezan con `g:` me tira error y no entiendo por qué.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <title>Whirlpool Argentina</title>
    <description>...</description>
    <link>www.whirlpoolstore.com.ar</link>
    <item>
        <g:id>
            <![CDATA[ 107 ]]>
        </g:id>
        <title>
            <![
                Aire Acondicionado Whirlpool - 3000 FC - Frio/Calor - Blanco
            ]]>
        </title>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[ (WB230AB) ]]>
        </description>
        <g:product_type>
            <![CDATA[ Electrodomésticos - Aires Acondicionados ]]>
        <g:product_type>
        <g:brand>
            <![CDATA[ Whirlpool ]]>
        </g:brand>
        <g:mpn>
            <![CDATA[ WB230ANACJ ]]>
        </g:mpn>
        <g:gtin>
            <![CDATA[ WB230ANACJ ]]>
        </g:gtin>
        <link>
            <![CDATA[
                http://www.whirlpoolstore.com.ar/aire-acondicionado-whirlpool-3000-fc-frio-calor-blanco/p?idsku=107
            ]]>
        </link>
        <g:image_link>
            <![CDATA[
                http://www.whirlpoolarg.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/155739_2
            ]]>
        </g:image_link>
        <g:price>
            <![CDATA[ 10.949,25 ]]>
        </g:price>
        <g:installment>
            <g:months>
                <![CDATA[ 1 ]]>
            </g:months>
            <g:amount>
                <![CDATA[ 10,949.25 ARS ]]>
            </g:amount>
        </g:installment>
        <g:condition>new</condition>
        <g:availability>in stock</availability>
    </item>
```

Comment: añade tu código como texto. es ilegible. [edita aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/54221/edit)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Comment: @Mariano: La pregunta se refiere a una función de hoja de cálculo :)

Comment: Véase: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=es

Comment: César: Es probable que el problema se deba al uso de "namespaces". Lamentablemente la pregunta se encuentra cerrada porque no está clara, por favor agrega una fórmula de ejemplo. También es recomendable que sigas el [tour] y [ask].

Answer (score 1):

En el código fuente del archivo XML mostrado `g:` es usado como prefijo para indicar que el nombre del nodo corresponde a un espacio de nombres, el cual se especifica la línea:

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
```

Una forma de especificar el nodo es usar `[nombre()='loquequiero']`.

Ejemplo

Asumanos que A1 tiene el URL del archivo XML, y que A2 tiene el nombre del nodo que nos interesa (sin el prefijo `g:`, dimos `loquequiero`. Una fórmula para obtener todos los nodos `g:loquequiero` es la siguiente:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[name()='"&A2&"']"
```

Relacionado:

Mi [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39493736/1595451) en inglés a [How to Import XML table Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39492485/1595451)